# create multiple folders using loops and inside this folders save excel sheet

Tags: python

I create a folder from loop how can save an excel sheet

```
path = os.path.dirname(('E:/python/Results/'))

for No_of_system in range(1,3):

    TaskAttribute = char.Task_Att(1)

    fle = os.mkdir(path + "\\" + str(No_of_system))

    w = pd.ExcelWriter('fle/withoutheuristic.xlsx')
    w1 = pd.ExcelWriter('fle/withheuristic.xlsx')
    for No_of_run in range(0,2):
     #RANDOMLY CREATING HOSTS
       for i in range(cf.Config.get_population_size()):
           chromo = (createindivisual.init_solution())
            Obj = Objective(i, chromo, TaskAttribute)

       d = {'Iteration': with_out_heuristic(Obj)[0], 'Best_fitness': 
            with_out_heuristic(Obj)[1], 'No.of_Task': 
            cf.Config.get_Task(), 'No.of_system': No_of_system}
       df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
       print(df)
       d1 = {'Iteration': with_heuristic(Obj)[0], 'Best_fitness': 
             with_heuristic(Obj)[1], 'No.of_Task': cf.Config.get_Task()}
       df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
       print(df1)
           
       df.to_excel(w,'sheet%s' % No_of_run, index=False)
       df1.to_excel(w1,'sheet%s' % No_of_run, index=False)
    w.save()
    w1.save()
```

This is my code but, can not save the excel sheet inside the create folders, anyone could help me plz

Comment: you don't seem to be passing the paths to w/w1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little messy so I'll just make a simpler example here.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


for path in ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]:
    os.mkdir(path)
    df.to_excel(path + "/filename.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")
```

So essentially for your code try adding the paths

```
w = pd.ExcelWriter(path + "/" + str(No_of_system) '/fle/withoutheuristic.xlsx')
w1 = pd.ExcelWriter(path + "/" +  str(No_of_system) '/fle/withheuristic.xlsx')
```

or something similar